flutter in_app_purchase (Subscription)
I am building an app with a monthly subscription plan using the in_app_purchase package in Flutter.
Subscription Validation: I currently check if the user is subscribed (isSubscribed = true) by triggering restorePurchases() every time the app launches. This ensures that the subscription status is always up-to-date, even if the user switches devices or deletes the app (or even deleting the local storage if i saved isSubscribe = true in SharedPreference or Hive). However, I'm concerned that repeatedly calling restorePurchases() might unnecessarily burden Google's API or something like that, i know that isn't the best approach but i still don't know how to solve it.
bool isSubscribed = false;
  final List<ProductDetails> products = [];
  final InAppPurchase _inAppPurchase = InAppPurchase.instance;

  Future<void> initialize() async {
    print("Initializing In-App Purchases");
    final bool available = await InAppPurchase.instance.isAvailable();
    if (!available) {
      print("In-app purchases not available on this device.");
      return;
    }
    const Set<String> _kIds = <String>{'test'};
    final ProductDetailsResponse response =
    await InAppPurchase.instance.queryProductDetails(_kIds);
    if (response.notFoundIDs.isNotEmpty) {
      print("Products not found: ${response.notFoundIDs}");
      return;
    }
    print("Products found: ${response.productDetails}");
    products.addAll(response.productDetails);

    // Start listening for purchase updates
    final Stream<List<PurchaseDetails>> purchaseUpdated =
        InAppPurchase.instance.purchaseStream;
    purchaseUpdated.listen((purchases) {
      _handlePurchaseUpdates(purchases);
    });
    await restorePurchases(); // this one is triggered everytime the user opens the app
  }

  void _handlePurchaseUpdates(List<PurchaseDetails> purchases) {
    for (var purchase in purchases) {
      if (purchase.productID == 'test') {
        if (purchase.status == PurchaseStatus.purchased || purchase.status == PurchaseStatus.restored) {
            isSubscribed = true; // Premium access granted
          emit(inAppPurchase_isSubscribed_True());
          print('the user is a subscriber');
        } else if (purchase.status == PurchaseStatus.error || purchase.status == PurchaseStatus.canceled) {
            isSubscribed = false; // Handle error/cancel
          emit(inAppPurchase_isSubscribed_False());
            print('the user is NOT a subscriber');
        }
        if (purchase.pendingCompletePurchase) {
          InAppPurchase.instance.completePurchase(purchase);
        }
      }
    }
  }

  void purchaseSubscription(ProductDetails productDetails) {
    final PurchaseParam purchaseParam = PurchaseParam(productDetails: productDetails);
    InAppPurchase.instance.buyNonConsumable(purchaseParam: purchaseParam);
  }


  restorePurchases() async {
    try{
      await _inAppPurchase.restorePurchases();
    }catch(error){
      print("restoring purchase error ||||||");
    }
  }

If I decide to save isSubscribed = true locally (e.g., using Hive), how can I ensure that access to premium features expires after the subscription period (30 days) ends? For example:
A user subscribes and the app saves isSubscribed = true in local storage.
If the user cancels their subscription after a few days or refunds his money back, the locally stored isSubscribed remains true, allowing unauthorized access to premium features until the 30 days pass.
Even with a "Restore Purchases" button, the local storage might incorrectly reset the subscription period (e.g., for 30 days) instead of aligning with the actual remaining subscription time.
